.NET 8 SPA Identity
I try to use SPA Identity in .NET 8 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0#test-registration
It works fine, but I need two things:

change e-mail texts - framework sending some standard text, but i need send my own html template

after registration I need start some background process


I am not able to find how to do that... any advice or example?
Thank you

If you want to modify the API endpoints based on what you want, I suggest you could check this source codes.
You could copy and paste it inside your projects and modify the MapIdentityApi method.
Like this :
public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapIdentityApi<TUser>(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)

To create a new one:
public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapMyIdentityApi<TUser>(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)

Inside the MapMyIdentityApi method, you could define your custom logic inside it.
For example:

change e-mail texts - framework sending some standard text, but I need send my own html template

Inside this source code, it contains below code, which you could modify it according to your requirement.
    async Task SendConfirmationEmailAsync(TUser user, UserManager<TUser> userManager, HttpContext context, string email, bool isChange = false)
    {
        if (confirmEmailEndpointName is null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("No email confirmation endpoint was registered!");
        }

        var code = isChange
            ? await userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, email)
            : await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

        var userId = await userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary()
        {
            ["userId"] = userId,
            ["code"] = code,
        };

        if (isChange)
        {
            // This is validated by the /confirmEmail endpoint on change.
            routeValues.Add("changedEmail", email);
        }

        var confirmEmailUrl = linkGenerator.GetUriByName(context, confirmEmailEndpointName, routeValues)
            ?? throw new NotSupportedException($"Could not find endpoint named '{confirmEmailEndpointName}'.");

        await emailSender.SendConfirmationLinkAsync(user, email, HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(confirmEmailUrl));
    }

    return new IdentityEndpointsConventionBuilder(routeGroup);
}


after registration I need start some background process

Inside the MapIdentityApi method, it contains the register post api code, you could also modify it based on your opinion:
    // NOTE: We cannot inject UserManager<TUser> directly because the TUser generic parameter is currently unsupported by RDG.
    // https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47338
    routeGroup.MapPost("/register", async Task<Results<Ok, ValidationProblem>>
        ([FromBody] RegisterRequest registration, HttpContext context, [FromServices] IServiceProvider sp) =>
    {
        var userManager = sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();

        if (!userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(MapIdentityApi)} requires a user store with email support.");
        }

        var userStore = sp.GetRequiredService<IUserStore<TUser>>();
        var emailStore = (IUserEmailStore<TUser>)userStore;
        var email = registration.Email;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || !_emailAddressAttribute.IsValid(email))
        {
            return CreateValidationProblem(IdentityResult.Failed(userManager.ErrorDescriber.InvalidEmail(email)));
        }

        var user = new TUser();
        await userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, email, CancellationToken.None);
        await emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, email, CancellationToken.None);
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, registration.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return CreateValidationProblem(result);
        }

        await SendConfirmationEmailAsync(user, userManager, context, email);
        return TypedResults.Ok();
    });

At last, inside the program.cs use the new mapidentityapi method like below:
app.MapMyIdentityApi<IdentityUser>(); 

